# Calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated column that removes 7 characters from the front and 2 from the back of the title column. I can get the formulas (below) to work interdependently but when I combine them I get a syntax error.

=RIGHT(Title,LEN(Title)-7)

=LEFT(Title,LEN(Title)-2)

Is there a way of combining them to 1 formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1234567TEXT12
```

Length = 13

```
RIGHT( Title , LEN(Title) - 7 )

TEXT12
```

**Length of Title is still 13**

```
LEFT( Title ,  LEN(Title) - 2 )
```

So LEFT needs to work on your RIGHT result, not the Title

```
LEFT(  RIGHT(Title,LEN(Title)-7)  ,   LEN(  RIGHT(Title,LEN(Title)-7)  ) - 2 )
```

*disclaimer: I did not test the Formula*